# Selenium Python - Auto login with cookie getting domain mismatch error

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

How to handle auto SSO login with Selenium ?
For example, during authentication on [www.corportatedomain.com](http://www.corportatedomain.com), it redirecting to another domain [www.anotherdoamin.com](http://www.anotherdoamin.com) and then it authenticate the user with SSO login. After successful login, it displays desired page.
To achieve this type of auto login in Selenium, using below Python scripts, it throws an error -
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain: Cookie 'domain' mismatch.
Is there any solution ?

Chrome version: 97.0.4692.99
Selenium version: 4.1.0
Chrome Webdriver version: latest

```
import time
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

# Capturing cookies
# Comment this code when loading cookies
driver.get("https://www.corportatedomain.com")
time.sleep(10) # Pausing program for user to enter credentials
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))

#Comment this code when capturing cookies
driver.get("https://www.corportatedomain.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```